# Android - Database designing for Mapping or pics?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dictionary

I need your help in designing my database.

I have 2 spinners; each one has 10 values.

Each value from the first spinner is related with the 10 values from the other. 
In other words, its like a map paths so when you are on the 1st place, your options are 9 from the other spinner, and each option has a specific picture for it, if you see what I mean.

And option 2 (from first spinner) has 9 options (from second spinner) etc..

So there will be almost a 100 pictures.

I was thinking of 10 tables..... each option from the first spinner has the 9 from the other

Now I need your help on how I am gonna design my database.
Any ideas related to the subject would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You want one table, not ten.

```
Table: SpinnerMapping
Spinner1    INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(Spinner1 BETWEEN 1 AND 10)
Spinner2    INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(Spinner2 BETWEEN 1 AND 10)
Picture     ...image type...  NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(Spinner1, Spinner2)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but can you explain alittle bit more

Comment: You have two sets of spinner values.  You store the value for spinner 1 in the column Spinner1; I assumed it was an integer in the range 1..10.  Associated with each value of spinner 1, there is a set of values for spinner 2.  Again, I assumed integers 1..10, but that's an assumption.  For each legitimate combination of values, you have a picture.  This table records the picture associated with a given value from spinner 1 and a given value from spinner 2.  The primary key specification says "thou shalt not have two pictures for one combination of Spinner1 and Spinner2".

Comment: Clearly, you might have different types and ranges for the spinner values; adapt the suggestion to suit.  You might have other columns in this table that characterize the spinner combination.  You might have other tables to describe the sets of spinner values that can exist at all (and you would likely use foreign keys to ensure that the values in the SpinnerMapping table are valid.  I've not specified a type for the image; it is likely a BLOB, but I'm not sure about SQLite and what it supports.  There really isn't much else to be said, I think.

Comment: am so sorry for not replying sooner but ive been away and thank you very much for your answer its been very helpful for me but can you give me examples of that (code examples)

Comment: No; I don't know how you're handling your spinner IDs, and I don't program on Android or with SQLite.  You will need to take it from here.